# State is not updating while passing it as props

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In my application I have created two reusable components one is Carousel and another one is button. Once click on button I passed an attributes like(posts,users,comments) which information are need to be fetched from the Api and showing them as Carousel format. But while clicking on "users" I am getting the information of posts and "users" for comments. So it is not behaving as expected. Here is the code ..

**Testimonail component:**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Testimonials() {
  const [testimonail, setTestimonial] = useState();
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/${testimonail}?_start=0&_limit=5`
    )
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => setItems(json));
  }, [testimonail]);
  const handleClick = (post) => {
    console.log("targetId", post);
    setTestimonial(post);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Carousel items={items} />
      <Button
        id={"posts"}
        btnName={"Post"}
        classes={"btn-primary mr-2"}
        onClick={() => handleClick("posts")}
      />
      <Button
        id={"users"}
        btnName={"User"}
        classes={"btn-info mr-2"}
        onClick={() => handleClick("users")}
      />
      <Button
        id={"comments"}
        btnName={"Comment"}
        classes={"btn-dark mr-2"}
        onClick={() => handleClick("comments")}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Carousel Component**

```
export default function Carousel({ items }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <OwlCarousel items={1} className="owl-theme" loop nav margin={8}>
          {items.length > 0
            ? items.map((item, id) => {
                return (
                  <div className="main-conatainer" key={item.id}>
                    <div className="testimonail-block">
                      <div className="left-images">
                        <img
                          className="img"
                          alt={"testimonial-images"}
                          src={"assests/images/1.png"}
                        />
                      </div>
                      <div className="posts">
                        <p>{item.body}</p>
                        <div className="testimonial-title">{item.title}</div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                );
              })
            : ""}
        </OwlCarousel>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: A working snippet would help here, but this could be React and it consolidating the DOM tree, you might find because your `OwlCarousel` props never change, React doesn't re-render correctly, could you try doing -> `<Carousel items={items} key={testimonail} />`  this will force React to re-render on `testimonail` change regardless.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I checked with that approach which is not working though.

Comment: can you post a link to a codesandbox that shows the issue properly?